# NGINX + Springboot (with Spring Security) 401 problem

Tags: java, docker, nginx, spring-security

I have a Springboot app running behind Nginx whereby upon load of the screen, the ui will invoke the springboot endpoint (PermitAll - no auth required) and return data back to the client.  However, when accessing the endpoint, it returned 401 and 200 alternately.

The **Nginx** entry is quite simple.

```
location /v1/auth {
    include /etc/nginx/shared.conf;
    proxy_pass http://user-svc;
}
```

the **upstream** is

```
upstream user-svc {
    server user-svc:8080;
}
```

the **shared.conf** looks like

```
error_page 405 =200 $uri;
# proxy_cache my_cache;
# proxy_cache_valid 200 30s;
# proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
# proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
# proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
proxy_no_cache $http_cache_control;
proxy_cache off;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#proxy_set_header X-forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java-base-image as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY ./src ./src
RUN mvn -o clean install -DskipTests spring-boot:repackage

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 jdk11-base-image
COPY --from=builder /app/target/user-svc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/user-svc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "user-svc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  user-svc:
    container_name: user-svc
    image: user-svc:latest
    expose:
      - "8080"
    networks:
      - private-network
    environment:
      TZ: Asia/Singapore
      SERVER_PORT: 8080
      DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/user
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASS: password
networks:
  private-network:
    external: true
```

The problem only occurred when accessing via Nginx.  Accessing it directly, via docker container or standalone (via Intellij) everything is working fine where http 200 is always returned.

My expectation is to received a 200 code always since this endpoint doesn't require any authentication at all.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: show us dockerfile.

Comment: i have updated above and added Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml content